# How do you use Ruby blocks to conditionally execute something?

Tags: ruby, function, block, yield

I recently purchased the book *Seven Languages in Seven Weeks* and have been reading through the chapter on Ruby. In the section which introduces blocks (page 40), a code sample is given which illustrates the use of blocks for the purpose of conditionally executing something:

```
in_case_of_emergency do
  use_credit_card
  panic
end

def in_case_of_emergency
  yield if emergency?
end
```

This code doesn't make much sense to me, and the book doesn't provide much of an explanation. I was wondering if one of you Ruby gurus would mind helping me get my head around this one.

How can you have both a block and a function with the same name? How would you define "emergency?" I can't even create the block in IRB without it complaining:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `in_case_of_emergency' for main:Object
    from (irb):1
    from :0
```

And how would you invoke this code to demonstrate how it works? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First off: the two are in the wrong order. You need to define `in_case_of_emergency` first.

Second: You don't name blocks; therefore, it is incorrect that there are two things named `in_case_of_emergency`. One is a function definition, while the second is the function **invocation** of that same function.

So, step-by-step:

```
def emergency?
  return rand(2) == 0
end
```

Let's say you have this function that returns `true` half the time, and `false` half the time, randomly. (Boy, that's a lot of emergencies!) Then:

```
def in_case_of_emergency
  yield if emergency?
end
```

This defines a function named `in_case_of_emergency`. When called, it executes `yield if emergency?`, which is a statement `yield` modified by the conditional `if`. This is syntactic sugar for

```
if emergency?()
  yield
end
```

Note that Ruby does not require brackets for function invocation, thus we can drop them; and if there is only one statement inside an `if`, you can write it on the same line as above (obviating the need for an `end`).

Next, we have a function invocation:

```
in_case_of_emergency do
  use_credit_card
  panic
end
```

This calls the function we just defined, `in_case_of_emergency`, passing it a block to execute. These are the two statements (`use_credit_card`, `panic`) that would be executed by `yield` - but only if the `emergency?` evaluates to `true`.

Does this make more sense now?

Comment: Amadan is right. @Steve Are you sure that the book gave the code in that order?

Comment: Yes, that was the order given in the book.

Comment: I recommend switching books. =/ http://programmingzen.com/ruby-and-rails-recommended-books/

Once I learned the syntax, I've learned the most from documentation.

Comment: @RyanScottLewis I'm willing to bet there was more context given in the book.  It's not reasonable to judge the book based on the small extraction of code given here without full context.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to other answers, it may be easier to understand blocks if you drop the `yield` keyword and treat blocks in methods like the Procs they actually are.

```
# for testing purposes, let's always have `emergency?` return `true`
def emergency?
  true
end  

def in_case_of_emergency(&block)
  block.call if emergency?
end

in_case_of_emergency do
  puts "AHH! Emergency! Help!", "Seriously, I'm freaking out!"
end
```

See how much easier it is to realize that the block is actually an argument?

Answer (score 2):

that's simple, that is the method:

```
def in_case_of_emergency 
  yield if emergency?
end
```

and that is the call to your method:

```
in_case_of_emergency do
   use_credit_card
   panic
end
```

wheres

```
do
   use_credit_card
   panic
end
```

is an argument. Ruby methods can implicitly take blocks as arguments. What happens is that
`yield` will execute the block you provided. In your case `yield if emergency?` means "execute provided block if conditions are met".